# Material 2 Form Control Select Not working with Async Source

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular4-forms

I am running Angular 4.3.4 with Material 2.0.0-beta.12 and I am having issues when trying to create a mat-select to generate a dynamic mat-option list from an asynchronous source. All I get is the placeholder and the dropdown doesn't expand. I don't even receive and error code.

Here is a sample of my code **UPDATED**:

```
 <form [formGroup]="snoozeForm" novalidate>
  <div fxLayout="column">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select formControlName="snooze_reason">
        <mat-option [value]="reason.attributes.snooze_reason_code" *ngFor="let reason of reasons">{{ reason }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

As you can see **reasons** is the array that gets dynamically populated. I must be overlooking something simple, but I am sure **reasons** is getting populated.

Here is where I populate the array:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.generateForm();
  this.httpService.getSnoozeReasons()
    .subscribe( res => {
      this.reasons = res;
    }, (error: any) => {
      const msg: Message = { title: 'Frontend API Error', textbody1: '' };
      if (error.message) {
        msg.textbody1 = <any>error.message;
        msg.textbody2 = `Task-details component - Snooze reasons`;
      } else {
        msg.textbody1 = `HTTP ${error.status}: ${error.statusText}`;
        msg.textbody2 = `Task-details - Snooze reasons: ${error.url}`;
      }
      this.messageService.createMessage(msg);
    })
  ;
}

generateForm(): void {
  this.snoozeForm = this.fb.group({
    snooze_reason: ['', [Validators.required]],
    snooze_hour: ['', [Validators.pattern('[0-9]*'), Validators.max(72)]],
    snooze_minute: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(5), Validators.pattern('[0-9]*')]]
  });
}
```

[image]

Has anyone had this issue with asynchronous data and the Select form control?

Comment: **"but I am sure reasons is getting populated"** so how does it look like when you console log it? :)

Comment: and what is `reason`? and why is it used as `value` there?

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot I have added, reasons is an array of objects, therefore, reason is an object and value will be assigned a property of that object.

Comment: Your code looks good to me, only issue I see is that you should show some property in your interpolation.. `{{reason.type}}` for example in your dropdown, but that is not the issue, you'd at least see `[object Object]` in your dropdown despite that. Could you perhaps create a plunker/stackblitz that showcases the issue? As an unrelated detail, no need to use `novalidate` anymore, it's applied automagically by Angular nowadays.

Comment: Yea, I am thinking of trying to replicate the issue with a much simpler version this weekend. I didn’t realize there was no need for the novalidate anymore. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Guillodacosta!

I had another pair of eyes to validate that the code was correct. I believe my issue now is that I have conflict with my UI packages. Ng-Bootstrap maybe causing my Material 2 Select to not render properly.

Over the past weekend I took some time to replicate my scenario, and validated that the code I have should work with the asynchronous data populating the Material 2 Select Drop-down.

Comment: Finally, got around to removing Ng-Bootstrap and now my code **WORKS!!!**

Answer (score 5):

I think that problem not is the reasons async array, else wise when you use the formControlName="snooze_reason", if you will try delete formcontrolname, the "select" work's fine. This happen because the controls from Angular forms need be declared as child of form group.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-select-angular',
  templateUrl: 'material-select-angular.html',
})
export class MaterialSelectAngular implements OnInit {
  formParent = new FormGroup({
    snoozeReason: new FormControl()
  });
  reasons = [];
  
  ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.reasons = [
        {prop: 'something'},
        {prop: 'anything'},
        {prop: 'some'}
      ];
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="formParent">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName="snoozeReason" placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let reason of reasons" [value]="reason.prop">
      {{ reason.prop }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: Added more details for reference. As you can see I am using the FormBuilder service. I only get this issue when I am using async source of data. I tried using the **async |** like how it is used in autocomplete but got more errors.

Answer (score 0):

in my case mat-select was not opening when options came from `Observable` (with async pipe), finally i solved my problem by an empty mat-option. you can hide it by style ;)

```
<mat-select [formControl]="..." (focusin)="loadLazy(...)">
    <mat-select-trigger>...</mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option style="display: none" disabled="disabled">--select item--</mat-option>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let iOption of Options | async">
        <mat-option [value]="iOption.name">{{iOption.value}}</mat-option>
    </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

back:

```
protected loadLazy(...): Observable<any> {
  if (!this.Options)
    this.Options = new Observable(x => x.next(...));
  return this.Options;
}
```